# Is a pair of boots hanging outside of a door a sign of brothel?

Tags: realism, the-alienist

In the TV show, *The Alienist*, episode 1, after the commissioner orders the brothel to be shutdown, they simply move across the street and re-open for business again.

The brothel owners hang a pair of women's boots outside of their door. Is it the sign for a brothel back then in New York?

Comment: hmm...this question is familiar but I can't recall where I saw it.